# Define an array of structs using hydras

Tags: python, c

I am using [hydras](https://pypi.org/project/Hydras/) to convert my C structs to python structs, to be able to communicate between an embedded device running my C code and my python code using pyserial.

My C struct looks like so:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t packet_index;
    uint32_t rssi;
    uint32_t packet_data[37];
} packet_t;

typedef struct {
    float32_t total_average;
    packet_t channel_packets[3];
} message_t;
```

My python code:

```
from hydras import *

class packet_t(Struct):
    pakcet_index = uint32_t
    rssi = uint32_t
    packet_data = Array(37)

float32_t = Float
class message_t(Struct):
    total_average = float32_t
    channel_packets = Array(len(packet_t)*3) # TODO: Change
```

Is there any way I can define an array of packets without having to treat them as an arbitrary array?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the second parameter of the array constructor is the type of the array.

You can write `Array(3, packet_t)` and `Array(37, uint32_t)`